# React Navigation Push screen inside another tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

I have tab navigators and stack navigator nested as follows:

```
- Tab_1
-------- Stack_1
-------- Stack_2 
-------- Stack_3
- Tab_2
```

I want to navigate to `Stack_2` from inside `Tab_2` with id parameters.

I can use

```js
navigation.navigate("Tab_1", {screen: "stack_2", params: {id: "abcd"}})
```

but this won't refresh the screen if I want to navigate again with id `efgh`. I would easily use push if I was inside the stack navigator, but as I am inside another tab I can't use that.

So far I have tried

```js
 navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: "Tab_1", params: { screen: "Stack_2", params: { id: "abcd" } } }] });
```

This does the job but then I can't go to `Stack_1` which is the main screen of `Tab_1` as the back button does not appear and also pressing on `Tab_1` icon does nothing.

How can I achieve the same result as `navigation.push` in here from inside another tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getId` prop on `Stack.Screen`:

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="stack_2"
  component={Stack2}
  getId={({ params }) => params.id}
/>
```

This tells React Navigation to add a new screen for the new ID, which is the behavior you want.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid